# How can I select clicked content?

Tags: python, jquery, html, django

How can I select clicked content?Now I am making a system when I click a button, the data is shown in nav tag.
I wrote codes in views.py

```
class TopView(TemplateView):
    model = Data
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['data'] = Data.objects.all()
        return context
```

When I click a button, all data is shown in nav tag of index.html.I want to show only clicked data in nav tag.I think I wrote codes so, but what is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

```
<html lang="ja">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HOMEPAGE</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
   nav {
    width: 312px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    transform: translate(312px);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #FFF;
   }
   nav.open {
    transform: translate(0);
   }
  </style>
</head>

<script>
$(function(){
  $('.btn_menu').click(function(){
    $(this).next('nav').toggleClass('open');
  });
})
</script>
<body>

    <section id="center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn_menu">
                            AAA
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn_menu">
                            BBB
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn_menu">
                            CCC
                        </button>

    </section>

    <nav>
        <h2>HOMEPAGE</h2>
        <!---->
　               <h4>AAA</h4>
　               <p>aaa</p>
        <!---->
　               <h4>BBB</h4>
　               <p>bbb</p>
        <!---->
　               <h4>CCC</h4>
　               <p>ccc</p>
        <!---->
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet for the same?

Comment: user9673470  check my edited solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your rendered HTML you need to do like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('nav h4, nav p').hide();
  $('.btn_menu').click(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    $('nav h4, nav p').hide();
    $('h4, p').each(function(){
      if($.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase()) == $.trim(obj.text().toLowerCase())){
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('nav h4, nav p').hide();
  $('.btn_menu').click(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    $('nav h4, nav p').hide();
    $('h4, p').each(function(){
      if($.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase()) == $.trim(obj.text().toLowerCase())){
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="center">
  <button type="button" class="btn_menu">
      AAA
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_menu">
      BBB
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_menu">
      CCC
  </button>

</section>

<nav>
<h2>HOMEPAGE</h2>
<!---->
  <h4>AAA</h4>
  <p>aaa</p>
<!---->
  <h4>BBB</h4>
  <p>bbb</p>
<!---->
  <h4>CCC</h4>
  <p>ccc</p>
<!---->
</nav>
```

Comment: user9673470  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

problem lies in this line `$(this).next('nav').toggleClass('open');`
next() is used to find immediate siblings.

To fix this, you should use

```
$('nav').toggleClass('open');
```

Plus, you need to restructure your code, load your js/jquery in Head or Body (preferred) before `</body>`.